# Dash-Plotly App Authentication - Login Details Saved As Cookies/Heroku Hosted 'Type' Object error

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have incorporated an authentication functionality into my code based off of the official [Dash-Auth docs](https://dash.plot.ly/authentication). This app is to be hosted on heroku. Couple of things happen (Code is below) :

```
app = dash.Dash('app',server=server)
app = dash.Dash('auth')
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    (('abcde','1234',),)
)
```

1. Locally, the authentication works flawlessly, except that once you
   login into the app it saves the login info as cookies. Hence, if you
   would refresh the page or probably paste the link to a new window it
   wont ask for the login info again unless and until you clear you
   cookies in the browser.
2. Once the app is pushed to the heroku master it successfully deploys
   it, unfortunalely the app does not open due to an application error.
   On checking the heroku logs the error shown is below. This error is not shown if hosted locally.

> 'TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable '.

As per the [post](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-authentication-issue/9990) I have removed dash.ly so im sure the error has nothing to do with it. As per this [post](https://community.plot.ly/t/enabling-authentication/4714/7) around the 8th comment someone raises the issue of the login but the reply is not definitive.

> UPDATE1

: I believe there is a clash between the `app = dash.Dash('app',server=server)` and `app = dash.Dash('auth')` since the moment I remove the code,

```
app = dash.Dash('auth')
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    (('abcde','1234',),)
)
```

The app seems to run fine even after deployment to heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these 3 points:

Change the name of your app "auth" to __name__

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
```

Do NOT call the dash.Dash() function 2 times. Change this:

```
app = dash.Dash('app',server=server)
app = dash.Dash('auth')
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    (('abcde','1234',),)
)
```

To this:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,server=server)
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    (('abcde','1234',),)
)
```

Remove those 2 last commas from your password pairs. Then it will be like this:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,server=server)
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    (('abcde','1234'))
)
```